# I am going to start automated QA

Tags: automated-testing

I am going to start automated QA at my company.

But I don’t know where to start, please give me some idea's and basic steps

Comment: you should explain more in detail like which type of  automation you are going to start , in which programming language you have good command etc , which type of project will you do?

Comment: Cool story. But what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to do QA, you would need to develop some **problem-solving skills.** Like using google when you are trying to find some information.

You have much deeper problem than not knowing how to start QA.

And yes, I left out for you to google what "problem solving" is, and how it relates to what you want to accomplish. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The basic step to start is to know why are you going for Automation? (Save time, money, resource)
Then what is the objective of your automation? (Test new feature, regression...)
What is the scope of your automation? (UI, WS, ESB...)
What are the most critic features?
When you have a clear view about these, you will be able to choose tools to automate your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Google and read articles :) This might be a start: http://www.automatedtestinginstitute.com/home/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1093:how-do-i-get-started-with-test-automation&catid=54:faqs&Itemid=76

Maybe buy a book about the subject: http://www.testing-software.org/book/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something down a while ago: [Test Automation – Here are our Thoughts on it](https://blog.xceptance.com/2013/06/19/test-automation-here-are-our-thoughts-on-it/)

Today’s article can be seen as a survey reflecting our thoughts on web test automation in general. It basically lists personal experiences that we were able to gain in customer projects or conclusions that we arrived at in recent discussions on this topic.

Feel free to use these ideas and thoughts as input for your own discourse on test automation, whether it is about starting it, keeping it running, or just questioning it every once in a while.

We do not claim that this is the only way of seeing things, so as always we are more than open to new input, arguments, or just a simple “Nah. Never!”.

Note that some of these thoughts are directly related to web UI automation – just in case you can’t match locators, CSS, or XPath to your current automation problem... [read on](https://blog.xceptance.com/2013/06/19/test-automation-here-are-our-thoughts-on-it/)